# installing Basemap

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

I'm new to the whole linux installing procedure so please help me learn to actually debug this problem myself i'm pretty stuck right now.

I've read the guide to installing `Basemap` I have done what it tells me too [installing](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html)

I untar successfully and copy the untarred file to `/usr/local`. Since I don't have the GEOS library I install it as specified [link](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html), changing into `GEO` directory and exporting varibale `GEOS_DIR` as `/usr/local`. When I typed `./configure` `--prefix=$GEOS_DIR` It didnt work saying I didn't have permission after a little bit of frustration I wrote `sudo` in front of the command an it worked. Finally I typed make and then make install and it did not work the error log is long here is the last bit which i imagine might be enough to diagnose the problem:

```
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include/geos/util" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include/geos/util"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 Assert.h AssertionFailedException.h CoordinateArrayFilter.h GeometricShapeFactory.h GEOSException.h IllegalArgumentException.h IllegalStateException.h math.h Machine.h TopologyException.h UniqueCoordinateArrayFilter.h UnsupportedOperationException.h '/usr/local/include/geos/util'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos/util'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos/util'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include/geos" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include/geos"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 export.h geomgraph.h geomgraphindex.h geom.h geomUtil.h geosAlgorithm.h indexBintree.h indexChain.h indexQuadtree.h indexStrtree.h indexSweepline.h inline.h io.h noding.h nodingSnapround.h opBuffer.h opDistance.h operation.h opLinemerge.h opOverlay.h opPolygonize.h opPredicate.h opRelate.h opValid.h planargraph.h platform.h precision.h profiler.h spatialIndex.h timeval.h unload.h util.h version.h '/usr/local/include/geos'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include/geos'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 geos.h '/usr/local/include'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/include'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src'
Making install in algorithm
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm'
Making install in locate
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm/locate'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm/locate'
source='IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp' object='IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo' libtool=yes \
    DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/geos -I../../../include    -DGEOS_INLINE  -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long  -ffloat-store  -c -o IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/geos -I../../../include -DGEOS_INLINE -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long -ffloat-store -c IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp  -o .libs/IndexedPointInAreaLocator.o
../../../libtool: line 1128: g++: command not found
make[4]: *** [IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm/locate'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm/locate'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/algorithm'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Hopefully someone more knowledgeable with installing things can help me figure out what i should do at this point.

Cheers
Peter

Answer (score 0):

your error shows there is no `g++` package installed in your system . install it and recompile it and also install recommendation suggested for `Basemap`.
use commands:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```